# How can I test __attribute__((objc_precise_lifetime))?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

I'm trying to understand the exact behavior of `__attribute__((objc_precise_lifetime))` / `NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE` in different situations. This was my attempt at a minimum "working" example (to show where it might be necessary):

```
@interface Foo : NSObject @end
@implementation Foo
- (instancetype)init {
    NSLog(@"Foo init");
    return [super init];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Foo dealloc");
}
@end


int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Foo *foo = [Foo new]; // might need NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE...
        id __weak weakFoo = foo;

        NSLog(@"Foo: %@", foo);
        // foo is no longer used at this point, so it could be released

        NSLog(@"Weak foo: %@", weakFoo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is:

```
Foo init
Foo: <Foo: 0x10020ba00>
Weak foo: <Foo: 0x10020ba00>
Foo dealloc
```

So it seems ARC is autoreleasing the object (even with optimization turned on). How can I construct a simple situation where ARC will aggressively release an object that's no longer used?

Comment: I'm not real good at reading assembler, but there is no autorelease call in the output on Apple LLVM 5.1; moreover, removing the autorelease pool entirely gives the same log. ARC won't guarantee that the strong pointer is valid past its last reference, but it is within its rights to keep it anyway. Even machinations like `id __weak weakFoo = foo;
    void * voidFoo = (__bridge void *)weakFoo;
    weakFoo = nil;` don't change the printout. I'm not sure you can force a release without nilling the pointer. Cf. [Playing around with arc force release irritation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10669448)